# Amazion web services change region for virtual machine

Tags: amazon-web-services

i was wondering if there is an option in AWS to change the region for example for a virtual machine? i selected the wrong region

Comment: Can't you create a snapshot and move that to the other region?

Comment: yes thats an option but i was wondering if there is a way to edit the region instead of an migration..

Comment: nope. there is no way to change the region for a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to copy it to a new region, but not to change an existing instance to another region; you need to make a copy and relaunch it.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html